# php no actualiza la operacion insert into

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Tengo un script php que inserta datos en la BBDD mysql que le llegan de un form html (lo clásico) con insert into y luego otro script php lee la BBDD pero no lista el último dato insertado hasta que actualizo la página.
Cuando llamo al script que lista los datos ya está insertado el último dato pero no lo muestra salvo que la llame otra vez. Si listo los registros en el script 1 salen todos pero cuando voy al script 2 falta el último. He probado a meter un error en el script 2 y no da error hasta que doy F5 de modo que no está leyendo el script ¿quizás del buffer?

Script 1 El que introduce datos desde el formulario html

```
include "conexion.php";
$obs_exp="";
$fecha_fin_exp="0/0/0000";
$punto=$_POST['punto'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$categoria=$_POST['categoria'];
$fecha_inicio_exp=$_POST['fecha_inicio_exp'];

If (isset($_POST['fecha_fin_exp'])) $fecha_fin_exp=$_POST['fecha_fin_exp'];
If (isset($_POST['obs_exp'])) {$obs_exp=$_POST['obs_exp'];}
If (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email=$_POST['email'];}


if (isset($_POST['punto'])){
$query="insert into incidenciasListado (punto,tipo,categoria,estado,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin,obs_exp) values ('$punto','$tipo','$categoria','$estado','$fecha_inicio_exp','$fecha_fin_exp','$obs_exp') ";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
```

Script 2: El que lista los datos

```
    <?php
include "conexion.php";
$query="select num,punto,tipo,categoria,estado,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin,obs_exp from incidenciasListado order by num";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
//$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($res);


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th> num </th>";
echo "<th> punto </th>";
echo "<th> tipo </th>";
echo "<th> estado </th>";
echo "<th> categoria </th>";
echo "<th> fecha inicio </th>";
echo "<th> fecha fin </th>";
echo "<th> observaciones </th>";
echo "<th> acceder </th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($res)){

echo "<tr>";
$fecha=date_create($fila[5]);
$fecha1=date_format($fecha,'d/m/Y');
if ($fecha1=="30/11/-0001") $fecha1="";
$fecha=date_create($fila[6]);
$fecha2=date_format($fecha,'d/m/Y');
if ($fecha2=="30/11/-0001") $fecha2="";
echo "<td> ".$fila[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($fila[1])."</td>";
echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($fila[2])."</td>";
echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($fila[3])."</td>";
echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($fila[4])."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$fecha1."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$fecha2."</td>";
echo "<td>" .utf8_encode($fila[7])."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='aporteincidencia.php?num=".$fila[0]."'> acceder </a></td>";
echo"</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Script conexion.php:

```
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$bd);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"UTF-8");
// errores conexion

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo"Error en la conexión";
    exit();}

mysqli_select_db($con,$bd) or die("Error en la conexión a la BD");
```

Comment: Todo esto esta en una misma pagina de PHP?

Comment: dos páginas de PHP y otra de html

Answer (score 0):

En el script1 después de la linea

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Redireccionas a la vista,

```
if ($res == false) {
    echo "Error en la consulta";
} else {
    header('Location:nombre_script2.php');
}


mysqli_close($con);
```

Y debes de cerrar la conexión

Espero que te sirva...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta aunque sigue sin mostrar los nuevos registros hasta que no se pulsa F5, a veces incluso varios registros. Ya he añadido $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
mysqli_close($con);
if ($res == false) {
    echo "Error en la consulta";
} else {
    header('Location:incidencias.php');
}

Comment: Puedes imprimir el archivo conexion.php?

Comment: Estoy mirandolo, si se me ocurre algo ya lo publico pero de momento no se donde está el error. Yo lo hice con una tabla mía logicamente y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias. Una vez hecho el submit voy a  phpmyadmin  y aparece el registro pero no en el listado (hasta que pulse F5), a veces se han quedado hasta 2 ó 3 perdidos (siempre los últimos)

Comment: El error tiene que estar dentro del bucle while, simplifica los campos fechas a ver si das con alguna linea que te da problemas. Lo siento, no se me ocurre otra cosa.

Comment: Gracias Oscar: Ya he comentado las fechas y sigue igual. No sé si tendrá que ver con que num sea campo autoincremental.

Comment: Claro, quita a num de las consultas sql

Comment: Lo quitas del select y en la fila que recuperas lo tienes igual, el bucle while no lo tienes que cambiar

Comment: Si lo quito del select  no  puedo recuperar el valor de num que es PK ademas

Comment: El problema que veo es que cuando el script php llama al segundo script y desde éste vuelvo al primero, cuando nuevamente llamo al script 2 desde el primero ya no lo lee sino que lo busca en la caché. De hecho la primera vez me lista el último dato pero vuelvo desaparece hasta que pulse F5

Answer (score 0):

AL final he encontrado la solución. Parece que el problema es que no cargaba el segundo script y he forzado a cargar el script en vez de tomarlo de la cache enviando un parámetro dummy con la petición de la página.
He creado una variable $hora = time(); y le he pasado ese parámetro en la petición GET o sea añadiendo &p=  para que cada vez que salta a la nueva página crea que es una página nueva y no la busque en caché ya que la hora se irá cambiando.